# How to Buy "Exotic" Bonds as a Low Net Worth Individual?

Tags: investing, bonds, broker

I'm a low net worth individual looking into investing into Junk Bonds but I have no idea where to start!

I understand that you will need to buy through broker. But I am struggling to find brokers which offer investments into interesting bonds such as Peoples' Life Bonds (don't judge)

I only have around $1000 disposable cash from my savings, to use and I have found that most brokers will take fees upwards of $10 per trade.

How would you suggest I go about purchasing these bonds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are discount brokers which charge lower fees, which ones are accessible to you will depend on your country. Here's a list for the USA: https://the-international-investor.com/comparison-tables/online-discount-stock-brokers-comparison-table

But seriously, as a "low net worth individual", the *last* thing you should be doing is gamble away that money - and that's what buying junk bonds is: gambling, not investing. They're called "junk bonds" for a reason, namely that the well-considered opinion of most investors is that there is a high probability of the issuer defaulting on them, which means that the invested money is lost.